# How can all elements of sublists be changed to a type?

Tags: python, list, types, generator, sublist

Let's say I have a list of lists. The sublists can themselves contain sublists. What would be an efficient way to convert all elements of all sublists to a particular type?

Let's say it's something messy like this:

```
a = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
        [
        "a",
        "b"
        ],
        [
        10,
        20,
            [
            "hello",
            "world"
            ]
        ],
    4,
    5,
    "hi",
    "there"
]
```

The idea would be to convert something like it to this:

```
a = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
        [
        "a",
        "b"
        ],
        [
        "10",
        "20",
            [
            "hello",
            "world"
            ]
        ],
    "4",
    "5",
    "hi",
    "there"
]
```

Note that I'm looking for approaches to dealing with an arbitrary depth of sublists. I have a feeling that a generator could be used for this, but I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: There are a few questions that discuss traversing arbitrarily nested lists. The only difference here is that you want to call a function on each node you encounter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to do it recursively (your list is unlikely to be *so* nested as to cause a problem):

```
def to_string(L):
    return [ str(item) if not isinstance(item, list) else to_string(item) for item in L ]
```